# Get a range of records from a text file using Windows 10 Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to extract an arbitrary range of records (record x to record y) from a newline terminated file using Windows Powershell - The file that I am working with is over 7GBs (over 37 million records) making `Get-Content` a bit unreasonable when extracting records from anywhere other than the beginning or the end of the file because `Get-Content` loads the specified range of records into memory (which has been causing my system to behave badly).

```
(Get-Content -Path .\7GB.txt -TotalCount 10000000)[-1000..-1]
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to achieve this using the Windows 10 PowerShell?

Comment: have you tried experimenting with the `-ReadCount` parameter of `Get-Content`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) in parentheses will read the entire specified content into memory before proceeding. Don't do that. [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) allows you to extract a particular range from a given input list.

```
Get-Content 'input.txt' | Select-Object -Skip 50 -First 100
```

The above will give you the lines 51 through 150 from the input file.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the accepted answer I wrote my first Windows Powershell cmdlet utility that incorporates this approach. I've posted the source on GitHub under an MIT license:

https://github.com/autopulous/powershell.large.file.record.plucker